# Use of variable name in shell script

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi

First of all I'm sorry for a probable bad title, but I don't even know what to call this.

I'm trying the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
VAR1="28-00000202070c"
VAR2="28-0000018776d3"
VAR3="28-0000033a6174"

for sensor in VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
do
 echo "$sensor:  $$sensor"
done
```

The expected output would be:

VAR1:  28-00000202070c

VAR2:  28-0000018776d3

VAR3:  28-0000033a6174

The real output is:

VAR1:  24038sensor

VAR2:  24038sensor

VAR3:  24038sensor

and the strange prefix number keeps growing...

VAR1:  24039sensor

VAR2:  24039sensor

VAR3:  24039sensor

...

I'd like to ask:

1) What are the correct terms/keywords that describe what I'm trying to do here

2) How to get to the expected output

Thanks,
Joaoabs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that `sh` does not support, while `bash` does.

The correct syntax you should use is:

```
echo "$sensor ${!sensor}"
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/bash                 <----- note I changed /bin/sh to /bin/bash

VAR1="28-00000202070c"
VAR2="28-0000018776d3"
VAR3="28-0000033a6174"

for sensor in VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
do
 echo "$sensor ${!sensor}"
done

$ ./a
VAR1 28-00000202070c
VAR2 28-0000018776d3
VAR3 28-0000033a6174
```